# Python - checking if an element is in two lists at the same time

Tags: python, list

In Python, to check if an element is in two lists, we do

```
if elem in list1 and elem in list2:
```

Can we do the following for this purpose?

```
if elem in (list1 and list2):
```

Comment: The big question here is, why do you _want_ to write the second way, when you know the first way, and it's perfect for your needs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you cannot.

`list1 and list2` means "`list1` if it's empty, `list2` otherwise". So, this will not check what you're trying to check.

Try it in the interactive interpreter and see.

---

The simple way to do this is the code you already have:

```
if elem in list1 and elem in list2:
```

It works, it's easy to read, and it's obvious to write. If there's an obvious way to do something, Python generally tries to avoid adding synonyms that don't add any benefit. ("TOOWTDI", or "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.")

---

If you're looking for an answer that's *better* in some particular way, instead of just *different*, there are different options depending on what you want.

For example, if you're going to be doing this check often:

```
elems_in_both_lists = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Now you can just do:

```
if elem in elems_in_both_lists:
```

This is simpler, and it's also faster.

Answer (score 4):

No, the statement

```
if elem in (list1 and list2):
```

would not work for this specified purpose. What the Python interpreter does is first check list1, if found empty (i.e - `False`), it just returns the empty list (Why? - `False` and anything will always result in a false, so, why check further? ) and if not empty (i.e evaluated to `True`), it returns `list2` (Why? - If first value is `True`, the result of the expression depends on the second value, if it is `False`, the expression evaluates to `False`, else, `True`.) , so the above code becomes `if elem in list1` or `if elem in list2` depending on your implementation. This is known as short circuiting.

The [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) page on Short Circuiting might be a helpful read.

Example -

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2]
>>> list2 = [3, 4]
>>> list1 and list2
[3, 4]

>>> list1 = []
>>> list2 = [3, 4]
>>> list1 and list2
[]
```

Comment: +1, because I think this is a clearer explanation than mine or Ashwini's, with exactly the right examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

`list1 and list2` will return the either the first empty list (because empty list is considered a falsy value) or if all lists were non-empty then rightmost list will be used.

for example:

```
>>> [1] and [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [1,2] and []
[]
>>> [] and []
[]
>>> [] and [1,2]
[]
>>> [1] and [] and [1,2]
[]
```

Comment: Nope, `list1 and list2` does not return a boolean, it returns either `list1` or `list2`. Sure, it's true that `bool(…)` will return a boolean, but that has nothing to do with what happens in `in`.

Comment: You mean `list1 and list2`?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, but you could write it as:

```
{elem}.intersection (list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)?

```
all(elem in i for i in (list1, list2))
```

As @DSM pointed out, there is not need for `zip`.

Comment: That's something quite different.  Consider `all(2 in i for i in zip([2,3], [2,4]))`, for example.

Comment: @DSM Oh man, that's the only case it would fail correct?  I thought I was being clever :)

Comment: No, you can also consider `all(2 in i for i in zip([1,2], [0,1,2]))`.  Your code translates as `for every corresponding pair from list1 and list2 (up to whichever list is shorter), is elem in each pair?`  OTOH, `all(elem in i for i in (list1, list2))` would work, though.

Comment: `2 in itertools.chain(list1, list2)`, maybe?

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I'll udpate.  I don't know why I needed `zip`.  Is that clearer now?

Comment: @kiddorails: no, that's `2 in list1 or 2 in list2`, not `2 in list1 and 2 in list2`.  Clever, though, I wouldn't have thought of it!

Comment: @DSM, precisely. `chain` will make list of both lists' elements. And if 2 is in there, it is `True`. :)

Comment: @kiddorails: we're trying to check if an element is in both lists, though, so we need `and`, not `or`.

Comment: If you want to go crazy with an iterator solution, instead of `zip` or `chain`, you can try: `all(elem==a and elem==b for a, b in product(list1, list2))`.

Comment: @DSM: Yeah, sorry, `any`. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The all() function can be used here:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [2, 4, 6]

if all(elem in list for list in [list1, list2]):
    print("elem appears in both list1 and list2")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the code sample in question, boolean operator `and` will return one of the values tested ([Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), so you will be testing only against one of them, and that does not guarantee the correct result.

```
>>> elem = 1
>>> list1 = [2, 3, 0]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> if elem in (list1 and list2):
...     print "IN"
... 
>>> IN
```

Answer (score 0):

`(list1 and list2)` will evaluate boolean operation and return back last list - `list2` if both have elements.
So, no, that won't work.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [2, 4, 5]

list1 and list2
```

gives [2, 4, 5]

```
list2 and list1
```

gives [1, 2, 3]

```
if 1 in (list1 and list2):
  print "YES"
else:
  print "NO"
```

Will give No

```
if 1 in (list2 and list1):
  print "YES"
else:
  print "NO"
```

will give "YES"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for item in list1:
    if item in list2: 
        print item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
if all([element in l for l in [list1, list2]]):
```

...which I just found a way to expand for checking if multiple elements are in every list:

```
if all([all([x in l for x in [elem1, elem2]]) for l in [list1, list2]]):
```

I guess with only 2 lists and 2 elements you'd rather do two like the first one (and just write `and` in between), but if you some day need to check if 10 elements are in 4 lists, this may come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure when * became a thing, but it allows 'in' to work with nested lists

```
Lists = {
    'List 1': [
        '11',
        '12',
        '13',
        '14'
    ],
    'List 2': [
        '21',
        '22',
        '23',
        '24'
    ]
}

if '22' in [*Lists['List 1'],*Lists['List 2']]:
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Answer (score -1):

The shortest code to do this is to just concatenate the two lists into one by adding them and then checking, so like this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

print(1 in a + b)
print(5 in a + b)
print(9 in a + b)
```

However this isn't really efficient since it will create a new list with all of the elements in `a` and `b`. A more efficient way of doing this is to use the chain iterator from itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

print(1 in chain(a, b))
print(5 in chain(a, b))
print(9 in chain(a, b))
```

And if necessary it's also easy to add more lists or even a list of lists.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]

print(1 in a + b + c)
print(5 in a + b + c)
print(9 in a + b + c)

print(1 in chain(a, b, c))
print(5 in chain(a, b, c))
print(10 in chain(a, b, c))
print(9 in chain.from_iterable([a, b, c]))  # A list of lists
```

Comment: You're checking if it is in any of the lists, but I think he wants to check if it's in both.