# Find the number of words that occur in both strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, compare, text-processing

I want to write a code that compares me between two texts and tell me some identical characters (or some identical words)
How can I do this?
i dont want to use:

```
print(text1 == text2)
```

i except to something like:

```
a = "i from israel"
b = "hello i from london"

# *i* and *from* are in both strings = 2

c = "apple orange banana watermelon"
d = "apple is very healthy, also banana and orange"

# *apple* and *banana* and *orange* are in both strings = 3
```

I want to compare with low aggravation i mean, count words that are in both strings.
thank you

Comment: What is an example of an input and the output you're expecting?

Comment: Also, what code have you tried so far? And what does "low aggravation" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same words by doing this: `list(set(a.split(' ')) & set(b.split(' ')))`

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596491/8700480) answer.