# Why does the if statement run even if the input does not match the elements in the list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the input from the user and then checking if the input is present in the two lists. For some reason even if the input is 'x' the output is 'yes. I am not sure why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
texas  = ['austin', 'houston', 'dallas']
Newyork = ['albany','stony', 'nyc']
city  = input('enter city name?\n>>')
if city in Newyork or texas:
    print('yes')
else: 
    print('no')
```

Comment: because your `if` condition test is checking `if` the user input exists in the Newyork list `or` if the list `texas` "exists", hence, regardless if the user input is in the Newyork list, `texas` list will *always* exist (hence check for `texas` list is always `true`) ... hint: check `if` city is in *both* lists:  `if city in Newyork or city in texas:`

Comment: Duplicate of [Python - checking if an element is in two lists at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596474/python-checking-if-an-element-is-in-two-lists-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I realized that after people pointed it out. Thank you for replying and giving an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
texas = ['austin', 'houston', 'dallas']
Newyork = ['albany','stony', 'nyc']
city = input('enter city name?\n>>')
if city in Newyork or city in texas:
    print('yes')
else: 
    print('no')
```

Explanation: you have to check twice: if `city` in `Newyork` and if `city` in `texas`

Comment: explanation: `or texas` only checks if `texas` is != 0, or converts to boolean that is true.

Comment: @rockzxm Thank you. It works now. I am still trying to understand why my code does not work. if you could help with that I would be grateful.

Comment: @Speedster_knight as @KYL3R mentioned, in your code `or texas` checks if `texas != 0`. If it is not, then `print("yes")` comes